# R - Exctract multiple tables from text file

Tags: r, shell, dataframe

I have a .txt file containing text (which I don't want) and 65 tables, as shown below (just the top of the .txt file)

[image]

Does anyone know how I can extract only the tables from this text file, such that I can open the resulting .txt file as a `data.frame` with my 65 tables in R? Above each table is a fixed number of lines (starting with "The result of abcpred on seq..." and ending with "Predicted B cell epitopes") and below each of them is a variable number of lines, depending on how many rows each tables has. Then it comes the next table, and it goes like that until I reach the 65th table.

Comment: Do any of the lines not in the tables start with numbers?  You could start by reading in the file as lines and searching for the lines you want using regex or just a simple search for the column headers, then select the lines below that until you get to a blank line.

Comment: rather than a nigh useless image, can you post a larger text sample of the file (preferably just enough contiguous lines from the start of the file to show 2-3 complete tables? pictures are not code or data unless we're talking image processing and generally should not be used for anything but chart examples.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html  may get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the tables are the only elements that start with numbers, to grep for integers at the beginning of the line is indeed the best solution. Using the shell (and not R) the command:

```
grep '^[0-9]' input > output
```

did exactly what I wanted.